# error in mstate: msprep Error in rep(keep[, i], tbl) : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r

I am getting an error only when I add covariates to the Keep = statement for covariates.

Is there a way to resolve this error?

```
library("mstate")
tmat <- transMat(x = list( c(2, 3), c(3), c()),
             names = c("Deliv", "Hosp", "Death"))

cohort <- msprep(data=msprep_first_preg,trans=tmat, time=c(NA,"YEARS_HOSP","YEARS_DEATH"),
             status=c(NA,"HOSP","DIED"), 
             keep=c("SMOKE", "MARITAL", "PARITY"),
             id = "PATID")



Error in rep(keep[, i], tbl) : invalid 'times' argument
```

There has been a similar error in this link documented previously [Error message using mstate::msprep ??bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985306/error-message-using-mstatemsprep-bug?rq=4) but after I converted my data from tibble to data frame, the error persists.

Comment: Hey, welcome. The developers are saying to definitively have fixed this bug (See [Issue #3 in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/hputter/mstate/issues/3)). Maybe try to use the development version of the package with `devtools::install_github("hputter/mstate")`?
If the error persists, please report it as a bug over there in the GitHub repo.